# Data packet format and routing tables in RPL

Tags: contiki, cooja, rpl

I would like to ask what is the data packet format in RPL. Is it the same as IPv6.
Also what are the fields in RPL routing table, neighbour list, and parent list. I appreciate if you can provide references.

Thanks..